# LinearLayout Listener not working

Tags: android, listener, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout which I programmatically add buttons to , 
and I am trying to remove a button when pressed, but the listener isn't working..

```
// ingAddLayout - the layout which the buttons are added to//
     String txt = "Dynamic Button"; 
        int idCounter = 0;  

            final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.setMargins(10, 20, 30, 20);
            AddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                            {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) 
                                {
                                        Button btn = new Button(context);
                                        btn.setText(txt);
                                        btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                                        btn.setId(idCounter);
                                        didCounter++;
                                        ingAddLayout.addView(btn,params);
                                    }


                                }

                            });
```

the listener:

```
ingAddLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)  
    {               
        ingAddLayout.removeViewAt(idCounter-1);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is ingAddLayout??

Comment: the LinearLayout i add the buttons to.

Comment: did u add your LinearLayout id java by findviewById() ??

Comment: yes.ingAddLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dynamicIngsLayout);

Comment: u need to remove the button on pressing on button then y r u applying the onclick on layout???

Comment: i want 2 be able to add buttons and remove them when ever i want and depnding on which button i press.

Comment: @Neha , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1Q3fCs2TSY&feature=youtu.be

Comment: yes so u shd apply click on button na y layout..accoring to this code u r removing the last button added not the button u r clicking

Comment: @Neha , i want to listen which button is pressed!

Comment: u r not understanding wht i want to say

Comment: @Neha , can you explain to me again please how to implemet what is show in the youtube link? thankyou..

Comment: wht do u want to understand??? and ur you tube link is not working

Answer (score 0):

this was the answer in the end:

```
Button buttonview = inflator.inflate(button layout xml);
buttonview.setonclicklistener(listener);

 AddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                            {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) 
                                {

                                        ingAddLayout.addView(buttonview);
                                    }


                                }

                            });
```